# Magento2: Search products using filterable Attributes

Tags: magento2, product, attributes, search, layer

I'm trying to make a product search engine and i need add a filter attribute option.

(i am using \Magento\Catalog\Model\Layer\Category\FilterableAttributeList)

i obtain the list of attributes

```
    $filterableAttributeList = $this->_filterableAttributeList->getList();
```

After i obtain the values for each attribute

```
foreach ($filterableAttributeList as $filter) {

        $code = $filter->getAttributeCode();
        $name = $filter->getFrontendLabel();

        $entities = $this->_eavConfig
                            ->getAttribute(\Magento\Catalog\Model\Product::ENTITY, $code)
                            ->getSource()->getAllOptions();

}
```

and finally for each option i want to count the number of products that match with that option but always return 0.

```
        foreach ($entities as $entity){

            $label = $entity["label"];
            $value = $entity["value"];

            if($label == " ") continue;


            $queryValue = [];
            $queryValue[$code][] = $value;

                $products = $this->_catalogSearchAdvanced
                    ->addFilters($queryValue)
                    ->getProductCollection()
                    ->addStoreFilter($storeId);

                $total = $products->count();

    }
```

any idea?

Comment: may be the problem is your array  `$queryValue[$code][] = $value;` try instead `$queryValue[$code] = $value;`

Comment: no, isnt it. but thanks!

Comment: Did you got the solution ?